# migration from magento 1.9 to magento 2.0.2 using composer

Tags: magento2, error, migration, composer, xdebug

I'm trying to download magento2 from git using composer I always see this warning
about Xdebug I uncomment the line zend_extension in my php.ini file but I have the same warning can any one give me solution thank you [image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably edited the php.ini for the web server, not for CLI mode. Usually these are different!

To find out which ini file(s) are loaded on the command line, run:

```
php --ini
```

Comment: @sejdaH If the answer helped you, please take your time to accept it